# I get a breakpoint after the realloc. Why? And how can I make it right?

Tags: c, dynamic, breakpoints, realloc

The point of the program is to replace every succession of **2 or more** vocals with my name.
How can I make that reallocation successful?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    char vocale[] = "AEIOUaeiou", 
            sir[] = "Aana are muaulte meiree.";
    char *src = (char*)malloc(strlen(sir) + 1);
    src = sir;
    char name[] = "Marian";
    int count = 0, 
            i = 0;
    while (i < strlen(src)) {
        if (strchr(vocale, src[i])) {
            count++;
            i++;
        }
        else {
            if (count >= 2) {
                src = (char*)realloc(src, strlen(src) + strlen(name) + 1);
                insereaza(src, count, name, i);
                i = i + strlen(name);
                count = 0;
            }
            else {
                count = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    puts(src);
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: You "get a breakpoint"? What do you mean?

Comment: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Comment: `char *src = (char*)malloc(strlen(sir) + 1);
src = sir; .. memory leak.`

Comment: You realloc from the stack, this is why you have a crash. Replace the lines `char *src = (char*)malloc(strlen(sir) + 1);` and `src = sir;` by the line `char * src = strdup(sir);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a proposal with some changes, it is difficult because I don't know what insereaza does

```
void main() {
  const char * vocale = "AEIOUaeiou";
  char * src = strdup("Aana are muaulte meiree."); /* must be in the heap for realloc */
  const char * name = "Marian";
  int srcLen  = strlen(src);
  int nameLen = strlen(name);
  int count = 0, i = 0;

  while (i < srcLen) {
    if (strchr(vocale, src[i])) {
      count++;
      i++;
    }
    else {
      if (count >= 2) {
        src = (char*) realloc(src, srcLen + nameLen + 1); /* perhaps too large */
        insereaza(src, count, name, i);
        srcLen += nameLen; /* or srcLen += nameLen - count + 1 ? */
        i += nameLen; /* or i += nameLen - count + 1 ? */
      }
      else {
        i++;
      }
      count = 0;
    }
  }
  puts(src);
  _getch();
}
```